# How to get list of services in Azure ML?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there an API to receive list of published webservices?

I have workspace id and auth token, I can get list of projects and experiments, but I can't get list of services created from experiments. Specifically I need the URL in order to post requests.
[image]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/TNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.technet.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/02/52/JupRay-2.png))</sub>

In client api I see if we publish a new service we can get it, but do we have more options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R Azure ML API has that. Excerpt from https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/AzureML/blob/master/vignettes/getting_started.html :

`(webservices <- services(ws, name = "AzureML-vignette-silly"))`

Comment: Many thanks!

It seems like R package uses different host for ML API.

R - https://studioapi.azureml.net

Python - https://studio.azureml.net/api/